# PHP Issue with deleting from MySQL

Tags: php

I do have programming experience, but new to php. I do have an issue with an example I was doing from this tutorial. I looked over it millions of times, googled, ect ect. I don't have an idea why my code isnt working.

The purpose is to basically just test inserting and deleting in sql from php, using a button for Add Record and Delete Record. The Add record button works perfectly, but delete doesnt do a thing other than reload the page. Heres the code...

```
<?php // sqltest.php

require_once 'login.php';

$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);

if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_database, $db_server)
     or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());

if (isset($_POST['author'])   &&
    isset($_POST['title'])    &&
    isset($_POST['type'])     &&
    isset($_POST['year'])      &&
    isset($_POST['isbn']))
{
    $author = get_post('author');
    $title = get_post('title');
    $type = get_post('type');
    $year = get_post('year');
    $isbn = get_post('isbn');

    if (isset($_POST['delete']) && $isbn != "")
    {
        echo "worked!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"; 
        $query = "DELETE FROM classics WHERE isbn='$isbn'";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        if(mysql_affected_rows($result) > 0) echo 'user deleted';

        //if (!mysql_query($query, $db_server))
        //echo "DELETE failed: $query" . mysql_error();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "nooooooooooooooooooo";
        $query = "INSERT INTO classics VALUES" .
        "('$author', '$title', '$type', '$year', '$isbn')";
        if (!mysql_query($query, $db_server)) 
        {
            echo "INSERT failed: $query" . mysql_error();
        }
    }
}

echo <<<_END
<form action="sqltest.php" method="post"><pre>
Author <input type="text" name="author" />
Title  <input type="text" name="title" />
Type   <input type="text" name="type" />
Year   <input type="text" name="year" />
ISBN   <input type="text" name="isbn" />
<input type='submit' value='ADD RECORD' />
</pre></form>
_END;



$query = "SELECT * FROM classics";

$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());

$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
{
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo <<<_END
<pre>
Author $row[0]
Title $row[1]
Type $row[2]
Year $row[3]
ISBN $row[4]
<form action="sqltest.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="delete" value="yes" />
<input type="hidden" name='isbn' value="$row[4]" />
<input type='submit' value='DELETE RECORD' />
</form>
</pre>
_END;
}

mysql_close($db_server);

function get_post($var)
{
    return mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
}

?>
```

I have looked over this many times, still no idea why this won't work. Is it the for loop that is making this button not work? Note, you will see echo "worked!!!"; and in the else echo "noooooooo"; that was for me to test whether the button was being tested, yet nothing prints. So maybe i missed something in the button code itself? Also, no errors are printed, and my editor (and myself) have missed the syntax error (if thats the case).

The code for the delete button is at the end, before I closed the DB.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Do a `var_dump()` on `$_POST` and make sure you're getting the values you are expecting

Comment: @JohnConde Hey just noticed this. Sorry to be a noob to you here but how would I go about doing that? New to this =(

Thank you for you input!

Comment: found the answer to this look at code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077539/php-cant-add-content-text-book-example
the reason it doesn't work is because the if/else statement for the delete is nested inside the other if statement.
if you unnest it it works.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is your first `if` block.

You're checking for the presence of the posted variables `author` `title` `type` `year` `isbn`. Whereas in your delete code the only variables sent are `delete` and `isbn`. Therefore the first `if` block is completely missed (including the delete code).

You need to modify your first `if` to be `if(isset($_POST)) { // a form has been posted`. Then it should work.

Another way to do it:

```
if(isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['isbn']) && !empty($_POST['isbn'])){
    //delete code here
}

if(isset($_POST['author']) && isset($_POST['title']) && isset....){
    // insert code here
}
```

EDIT: rewritten code:

```
<?php // sqltest.php

// I don't know what's in here, so I've left it
require_once 'login.php';

$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);

if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_database, $db_server)
     or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());

if (isset($_POST))
{

    if (isset($_POST['delete']) && !empty($_POST['isbn']))
    {
        echo "Deleting"; 
        $query = "DELETE FROM classics WHERE isbn='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['isbn'])."'";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        if(mysql_affected_rows($result) > 0) echo 'user deleted';
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Inserting";
        $query = "INSERT INTO classics VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['author'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['year'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['isbn'])."')";
        if (!mysql_query($query)) 
        {
            echo "INSERT failed: $query" . mysql_error();
        }
    }
}

// you don't need echo's here... just html
?>

<form action="sqltest.php" method="post">
    <pre>
        Author <input type="text" name="author" />
        Title  <input type="text" name="title" />
        Type   <input type="text" name="type" />
        Year   <input type="text" name="year" />
        ISBN   <input type="text" name="isbn" />
        <input type='submit' value='ADD RECORD' />
    </pre>
</form>

<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM classics";

$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());

// a better way to do this:
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<pre>
    Author <?php echo $row[0]; ?>
    Title <?php echo $row[1]; ?>
    Type <?php echo $row[2]; ?>
    Year <?php echo $row[3]; ?>
    ISBN <?php echo $row[4]; ?>
    <form action="sqltest.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="yes" />
        <input type="hidden" name='isbn' value="<?php echo $row[4]; ?>" />
        <input type='submit' value='DELETE RECORD' />
    </form>
</pre>

<?php
}

mysql_close($db_server);

?>
```

Comment: Same result =/ its acting exactly like you described it too. augh, thanks a lot for your input though!

Comment: I did try it, although when I tested it, it printed row[0] row[1] and when I hit delete it had the same result. =/ I am reading through the link you posted right now. Thank you for your input

Comment: @TheNoob please see my edit. I've rewritten your code to a) be more readable b) educate you on a few points (such as a better/easier way to loop through db rows) and c) hopefully fix your issue. Please have a look through and see if it works.

Comment: Okay, I see what you did. I didn't know you could do a loop and pop in and out of php like that. This did make the delete button work, but nothing deletes, instead I get this at the top

Deleting
Warning: mysql_affected_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\sqltest.php on line 21

Also, instead of the data being printed inside of row[0] ect, its actually printing row[0] which is something I can prolly fix. I just wish it would delete. The add buttons works still.

Comment: Ah 1. take $result out of mysql_affected_rows($result) so you end up with `mysql_affected_rows()`. That should work. However, the query has run by this point, so the query is working fine. The problem is the second issue you brought up. I did change my code just after I added it, because of the printing `row[0]` etc issue. I changed it to have <?php echo $row[0]; ?> have a look. Change that - ESPECIALLY the one where its `<input type="hidden" name="isbn" value="<?php echo $row[4]; ?>" />` and it should work now. :) Sorry about that.

Comment: I do have a question. Why is there the '.' before and after the 

".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['author'])." statements?

Comment: There was one issue. It was trying to insert every time the page loaded. So the first time it loaded it inserted blanks because the ffields were empty. Then affter that it kept complaining about how that all this crap is already in the db. although i did fix it by

<input type="hidden" name="insert" value="yes" />
and
if(isset($_POST['insert']) && !empty($_POST['isbn']))

is this how all buttons usually work? Thanks a ton! Helped a lot. =]

Comment: Hi, glad it helped. Don't worry about the upvotes, but you can click the green "tick" next to my answer to mark as the accepted answer. The "." before and after the statements are to concatenate the string. You should really do this in order to concatenate strings with variables. e.g. `$var = "world"; echo "Hello ".$var;` will echo "Hello world". You could also do `echo "Hello "."World"."!"` although its a bit pointless. Similarly you can do `$var1 = "Hello"; $var2 = "World"; echo $var1." ".$var2;` "Hello World". Hope that makes sense.

Comment: That's a bit strange. Normally `$_POST` shouldn't be set unless you've posted some variables. However, its probably good practice to do what you've done. :) The way I'd normally do it is to have a hidden field called "action" and in the insert form have its value as "insert" and in the delete have its value as "delete". Then when you test you can do: `if(isset($_POST['action'])){ if($_POST['action'] == "insert"){ // insert code } else if($_POST['action'] == "delete"){ //delete code }` You could also use a switch statement, which works in a similar way. http://w3schools.com/php/php_switch.asp

Answer (score 0):

Verify the method you used in your form. Make sure it's POST like this:

Form `action="yourpage.php" method="POST"`

and in your code above, replace the following:

```
$author = get_post('author');
    $title = get_post('title');
    $type = get_post('type');
    $year = get_post('year');
    $isbn = get_post('isbn');
```

with

```
$author = $_POST['author'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$isbn = $_POST['isbn'];
```

Finally, there is no need to check again if the `$isbn` is not null as you did it in your `isset()` method. So remove `$isbn!=""` in the if below:

```
if (isset($_POST['delete']) && $isbn != "")
    {
}
```

becomes:

```
if (isset($_POST['delete']))
    {
}
```

Since you are testing, checking if the user clicked the delete button is of less importance. So you can also remove it for a while and add it later because you are sure that, that code is accessible after clicking the delete button.

Answer (score -2):

You have no form field named `delete`, so it is impossible for your delete code path to ever be taken.

I'm guessing you're tryign to use the value of the submit button to decide what to do? In that case, you're also missing a `name` attribute on the submit button - without that, it cannot submit any value with the form. You probably want:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="DELETE RECORD" />
```

and then have

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && ($_POST['submit'] == 'DELETE RECORD')) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: There is a delete field in his form.

Comment: @rawkode: d'oh... didn't scroll far enough in that wall of code.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I did try, same result. This is just really annoying. lol Again thanks though