# Can't add content to database

Tags: php, mysql

This is based on an example in the O'Reilly book Learning PHP, MySQL, JavaScript and CSS, Second Edition.

I cannot add any records to the database via the interface. Whenever I try, regardless of what I enter, I get the exact same error:

```
column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

If I hit the ADD RECORD button more than two consecutive times without exiting the page in between, the program starts **deleting** records from the database.

```
<?php // sqltest.php

// Note: This example is different to the one in the book. It has
//       been amended to work correctly when deleting entries.

require_once 'login.php';
$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);

if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_database, $db_server)
    or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());

if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['isbn']))
{
    $isbn  = get_post('isbn');
    $query = "DELETE FROM classics WHERE isbn='$isbn'";

    if (!mysql_query($query, $db_server))   
        echo "DELETE failed: $query<br />" .
        mysql_error() . "<br /><br />";
}

if (isset($_POST['author']) &&
    isset($_POST['title']) &&
    isset($_POST['category']) &&
    isset($_POST['year']) &&
    isset($_POST['isbn']))
{
    $author   = get_post('author');
    $title    = get_post('title');
    $category = get_post('category');
    $year     = get_post('year');
    $isbn     = get_post('isbn');

    $query = "INSERT INTO classics VALUES" .
        "('$author', '$title', '$category', '$year', '$isbn')";

    if (!mysql_query($query, $db_server))
        echo "INSERT failed: $query<br />" .
        mysql_error() . "<br /><br />";
}

echo <<<_END
<form action="sqltest.php" method="post"><pre>
  Author <input type="text" name="author" />
   Title <input type="text" name="title" />
Category <input type="text" name="category" />
    Year <input type="text" name="year" />
    ISBN <input type="text" name="isbn" />
         <input type="submit" value="ADD RECORD" />
</pre></form>
_END;

$query = "SELECT * FROM classics";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    echo <<<_END
<pre>
  Author $row[0]
   Title $row[1]
Category $row[2]
    Year $row[3]
    ISBN $row[4]
</pre>
<form action="sqltest.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="delete" value="yes" />
<input type="hidden" name="isbn" value="$row[4]" />
<input type="submit" value="DELETE RECORD" /></form>
_END;
}

mysql_close($db_server);

function get_post($var)
{
    return mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
}
?>
```

Here is the sql file

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.1.50, for Win32 (ia32)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: 
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.1.50-community

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Current Database: `publications`
--

CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `publications` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;

USE `publications`;

--
-- Table structure for table `accounts`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `accounts`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
  `number` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `balance` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`number`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `accounts`
--

LOCK TABLES `accounts` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `accounts` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `accounts` VALUES (12345,1050.61),(67890,140);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `accounts` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `classics`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `classics`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `classics` (
  `author` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `year` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isbn` char(13) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`isbn`),
  KEY `author` (`author`(20)),
  KEY `title` (`title`(20)),
  KEY `category` (`category`(4)),
  KEY `year` (`year`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `author_2` (`author`,`title`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `classics`
--

LOCK TABLES `classics` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `classics` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `classics` VALUES ('Mark Twain (Samuel Langhorne Clemens)','The Adventures of Tom Sawyer','Classic Fiction',1876,'9781598184891'),('Jane Austen','Pride and Prejudice','Classic Fiction',1811,'9780582506206'),('Charles Darwin','The Origin of the Species','Classic Fiction',1856,'9780517123201'),('Charles Dickens','The Old Curiosity Shop','Classic Fiction',1841,'9780099533474'),('William Shakespear','Romeo and Juliet','Play',1594,'9780192814968');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `classics` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `classics52`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `classics52`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `classics52` (
  `author` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `year` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isbn` char(13) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`isbn`),
  KEY `author` (`author`(20)),
  KEY `title` (`title`(20)),
  KEY `category` (`category`(4)),
  KEY `year` (`year`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `classics52`
--

LOCK TABLES `classics52` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `classics52` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `classics52` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `customers`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `customers`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `name` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isbn` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`isbn`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `customers`
--

LOCK TABLES `customers` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `customers` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `customers` VALUES ('Joe Bloggs','9780099533474'),('Mary Smith','9780582506206'),('Jack Wilson','9780517123201');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `customers` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Current Database: `test`
--

CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `test` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;

USE `test`;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2012-12-26 18:43:24
```

Is my SQL database itself messed up? If that were the case how could it alter the functions of an independent program? If not, what's causing my error?

Comment: I can offer my .sql backup file and login file if anyone needs them to test the program.

Comment: You seriously might want to find a new book that has updated examples not using the `mysql_*` functions.  These are deprecated and should not really be used anymore.  Perhaps seek out a newer text if you are just new to PHP, so that you can learn the more appropriate way to do things.

Comment: This book is pretty recent. In any case, I'm starting to wonder if my computer's overzealous security system could be to blame here...

Comment: Does `echo PHP_EOL.'<!-- '.$query.' -->'.PHP_EOL);` after each query output the desired query string for each?

Comment: Why would it? What is that command supposed to do where?

Comment: Imported your dump. Copied you code. Everything worked fine. Have you got PHP error reporting turned on? Can you tell us what values you’re posting in your form submissions?

Comment: @David to check if the structure of your query looks any different from the one that initially filled the database. The error clearly indicates that the amount of values in your query does not match that of the columns in the `classics` table. For the record I tried your whole code and it just inserts the values without any error. An irrelevant suggestion: use `{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}` for the form action so that if you change the name of your file you won't be bothered to change these values.

Comment: check data type of field in mysql and echo your query.

Answer (score 1):

Check your insert against your classics table : `INSERT INTO classics VALUES" .
        "('$author', '$title', '$category', '$year', '$isbn')`

If you don’t specify the columns in your insert statement then your values have to match the number of columns in your table.

This might work if you’ve named your columns similar to your variables.
`INSERT INTO classics (author, title, category, year, isbn) VALUES " .
        "('$author', '$title', '$category', '$year', '$isbn')`

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the column count isn't right. Check if in your database you really have 5 columns(author, title, category, year, isbn). If not, you can change your query and specify your columns:

```
    "INSERT INTO `classics` (`author`, `title`, `category`, `year`, `isbn`) VALUES " .
    "('$author', '$title', '$category', '$year', '$isbn')"
```

For the deleting issues, I don't have any ideas.

Comment: I do indeed have five categories in the sql.

Comment: Did you try to specify the columns as in my example? Look closely at your 'classics'-table and use the right column names.

Comment: Shouldn't this line handle that?:

Comment: $author   = get_post('author');
    $title    = get_post('title');
    $category = get_post('category');
    $year     = get_post('year');
    $isbn     = get_post('isbn');